# Wrong scrollbar jxbrowser in jpanel

Tags: jxbrowser

I add a jxbrowser element inside a jpanel.
I load a webapps into the jxbrowser element.
Jxbrowser load it and shows vertical and orizontal scrollbar even if no needed.
If a I open the same webappa into jxbrowser demo browser I have no scrollbar.
Any idea? What can I check ?

Comment: Make sure that the size of the BrowserView in your JPanel and the Demo app is the same. Different web pages might display scrollbar depending on the size of the page. You might observe a different behavior because you have different size. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the problem again. I was able to reproduce the problem in your demo browser.  It seems that the problem is in rendering engine. Jxbrowser 5.2 demo browser renders the page well.  Jxbrowser 5.4.3 shows the wrong scroll bars